# Problem when changing a label by pressing some buttons

Tags: swift, xcode, button, label

I have 5 buttons and a label. When you press one of the buttons, its respective text appears on the label. And when you press the button again, the label clears the text.

I have that done on the code below. The problem is that I also want that, when you press another button (while the text of the previous button you pressed is still on the label) the text of that button appears on the label.

This is what I have now:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var agressionSelected: UILabel!
var buttonHasNoText: Bool = true

@IBAction func agressionBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
 
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        if buttonHasNoText {
            agressionSelected.text = "Button 1 pressed"
            buttonHasNoText = false
        } else {
            agressionSelected.text = ""
            buttonHasNoText = true
        }
    case 2:
        if buttonHasNoText {
            agressionSelected.text = "Button 2 pressed"
            buttonHasNoText = false
        } else {
            agressionSelected.text = ""
            buttonHasNoText = true
        }
    case 3:
        if buttonHasNoText {
            agressionSelected.text = "Button 3 pressed"
            buttonHasNoText = false
        } else {
            agressionSelected.text = ""
            buttonHasNoText = true
        }
    default:
        agressionSelected.text = ""
    }
}
```

I've read people with similar problems but they don't quite match with this one and I have been trying without any result. I'm new at coding and I don't know if I'm missing some basic thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two questions for clarity. Button 1 pressed and that is currently displayed on the label. Next, button 2 is pressed. (1) Are you wanting to **append** what is displayed on the label? Also, on a separate line? Next, let's say button 1, 2, or 3 is pressed -**after** question 1. What is the desired result? (2) Replace everything, edit based on the button pressed, or append - in the case of button 3 being pressed. How to do this is rather simple, but what you want isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Yes, sorry. When you press button, you display its text in a label. If you don't touch that button again for removing the text, and you press another button, that other buttons text would be appended to the label.

Comment: I was writing a longer answer than you already accepted - what do you want if the sequence of button touches are 1, then 2, then 3, then 2 - but it looks like you already have a good enough answer. Good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of just a basic modification to your code, you could check to see if the current label text is equal to the text you're trying to set it to. If not, you change the text. If so, you change it to empty:

```
switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            if agressionSelected.text == "Button 1 pressed" {
                agressionSelected.text = ""
            } else {
                agressionSelected.text = "Button 1 pressed"
            }
        case 2:
            if agressionSelected.text == "Button 2 pressed" {
                agressionSelected.text = ""
            } else {
                agressionSelected.text = "Button 3 pressed"
            }
        case 3:
            if agressionSelected.text == "Button 3 pressed" {
                agressionSelected.text = ""
            } else {
                agressionSelected.text = "Button 3 pressed"
            }
        default:
            agressionSelected.text = ""
        }
```

You make the code a little less repetitive by doing something like this:

```
let tagsToText = [1:"Button 1 Pressed", 2: "Button 2 Pressed", 3: "Button 3 Pressed"]
if agressionSelected.text == tagsToText[sender.tag] {
  agressionSelected.text = ""
} else {
  agressionSelected.text = tagsToText[sender.tag] ?? ""
}
```

In this version, you have a Dictionary of tags and their corresponding text. Again, if the text is already set to that value, then the label is reset to empty. If the text is different, it is set to the new value.